# Iterating through multiple arrays and pull data from each one

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array that contains multiple arrays in it (3 for now).
each array inside has multiple posts objects.

I'm trying to loop through those 3 arrays and each time to pull 1 post object from one of them and push it a new empty array that I've created in the same order that I'm pulling it one after the other.

```
// dynamic number
$count_posts_query = 9

//the array that contains 3 arrays with posts in it (dynamic can be more
)
$term_posts = array(
[0] => array( <--- contains 26 posts objects 
   [0] => {post object}.
   [1] => {post object},
   [2] => {post object},
   [... and so on 26 objects] 
 ) 
[1] => array( <--- contains 58 posts objects 
   [0] => {post object}.
   [1] => {post object},
   [2] => {post object},
   [... and so on 58 objects] 
 )
[2] => array( <--- contains 103 posts objects 
   [0] => {post object}.
   [1] => {post object},
   [2] => {post object},
   [... and so on 103 objects] 
 )
),

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count_posts_query; $i ++ ) {
 array_push( $new_terms_arrays, $term_posts[$i][ $i ] );
}
```

The Problem with this loop is that the $i is not correct it just goes 3 times and each time enter the position of the array and the object with the same $i number and then the other 6 objects are null and not Ascending correctly

Error Image -
https://i.ibb.co/4PxXxgw/Screenshot-at-Aug-10-09-15-20.png

Comment: Does it need to be the same posts each time? Do you have to ensure that selection is balanced? E.g. the same number of posts from each array?

Comment: your `$count_posts_query = 9` but `$term_posts` has only three arrays.

Comment: what does `$count_posts_query` represent? And how are you expecting to use it to build your new array?

Comment: @Scuzzy `$count_posts_query` is a dynamic number which represents the number of posts that I want to pull in total from the $_term_posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the array is always going to be the right length for the number of items your after, you can use `array_column()` to extract the next set of posts from each array and add this into the new array (using `array_merge()`).  So this takes all of the `[0]` items from the array, then the `[1]` items and so on...

```
$i=0;
$new_terms_arrays = [];
while ( count($new_terms_arrays) < $count_posts_query ) {
    $new_terms_arrays = array_merge( $new_terms_arrays, 
            array_column($term_posts, $i++ ));
}
```

Comment: Genius!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through the 3 items in the array, you could use the count of the `$term_posts` array itself instead of the hardcoded `$count_posts_query = 9`

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($term_posts); $i ++) {
 array_push($new_terms_arrays, $term_posts[$i][$i]);
}
```

As [Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren) points out, note that you use the value of `$i` for both indices. For the first that works as it is based on the count of the `$term_posts` array.

The issue arises that you use the same incrementing index for the second array, which is not guaranteed to be there.

If you want to pull 1 post object every time, you have to make sure that you  use an existing index.